# Unable to View the Applications under SCA modules list

Tags: sca

We are working on a migration of our BAW servers from on-premises to cloud platform.

We are able to successfully install the latest version server and proceed with the EAR deployments and configuration, while validation we noticed that we are Unable to View some of the Applications under SCA modules list but it is present in under Enterprise Application list.

Please guide on how to proceed with this issue

tried restarting the dmgr, server and nodeagent but nothing helped in fixing the issue.